# Numerical character recognition in Pytesser

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract, pytesser

I am working on a project that requires me to get prices from a commodity exchange. Unfortunately the exchange has no webservice or other plugin available that allows me to get the prices from the trading screen.

I figured that I could automatically make a screenshot of the prices and split all prices up in individual images. After that I process them with the Pytesser V 0.0.1 library for Tesseract 3.0.2 combined with Pillow 3.1.0 in Python v2.7. However, the conversion of the image to text (by the image_to_string function) is dramatic, as in most cases a 0 becomes an o or a 5 becomes an s and sometimes the conversion is random, which makes it difficult to just replace these characters. I have already resized the image to a larger size and used anti-aliasis, but the result does not get better. Is there a way to limit the set of characters to only digits and a dot for decimals? And how can the quality of the conversion be improved?

Perhaps my method is too tedious and you guys know a better way to do it? Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have an example of what image you want to work off?

Comment: Please, in next question, write less. You shouldn't explain with much details, but only essential to we reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to limit the set of characters to only digits and a dot
>   for decimals?

Yes! Using the package [pyslibtesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyslibtesseract):

```
from pyslibtesseract import TesseractConfig, PageSegMode
config_line = TesseractConfig(psm=PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_LINE)
config_line.add_variable('tessedit_char_whitelist', '0123456789.')
```

> And how can the quality of the conversion be improved?

You need use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) to improve the image quality.